# Get Dynamic FIeld data with ruby filter in logstash pipeline

Tags: logstash

I need to process data from a field with a dynamic fieldname that is specified in another (not dynamic) field, something like:

```
{
your_data_is_in : "dynamic_fieldname",
dynamic_fieldname : {"the data is here"}
}
```

I'm trying using a ruby filter over a logstash pipeline, with no success:

```
filter{
     mutate {
          add_field => { "dynamic_fieldname" => "%{your_data_is_in}" }
     }
     ruby {
          tag_on_exception => '_my_exception'
          code => '
               event.set("the_data_i_need", event.get("%{dynamic_fieldname}"))
          '
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some miss&hit , this is how I managed to do this:

```
code => ' event.set("the_data_i_need", event.get(event.get("dynamic_fieldname")))
      '
```